# xamarin.forms android service run twice after restarting it

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have this code that create an android service

```
[Service]
public abstract class LongRunningTaskService : Service
{
    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        Logs.Info("service started: " + this.GetType().ToString());

        try
        {
            Tasks.RunTask(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Task.run(() => SomeTaskFunction);
                    StopSelf();
                    Logs.Info("service ended successfully from main task");
                }
                catch (Android.OS.OperationCanceledException e)
                {
                    Logs.Warning("Error in Tasks.RunTaskWithoutWaitForResult", e);
                }
            });


            return StartCommandResult.NotSticky;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logs.Warning("error in OnStartCommand", e);
            return StartCommandResult.NotSticky;
        }
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        try
        {
            Logs.Info("service destroyed: " + this.GetType().ToString());

            base.OnDestroy();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logs.Warning("Error in service destroyed: " + this.GetType().ToString(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

when i create the service the first time it works ok, but when i destroy it from outside the service and recreate it with the same function to run there are 2 tasks running at the same time.

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: What you mean by " there are 2 tasks running at the same time."? Your service got started twice at the same time? You may try to set a bool flag in your service and make sure it only run once.

Comment: @Grace Feng - MSFT what i mean is that i started a service, killed it, started it again, and i see 2 instances of the service - meaning the stop service didn't work